# Passing image data

Tags: image, uitableview, parse-platform

I am creating an application where I visualize my registered users to my databrowser of Parse.com (in a TableView Controller) and step data of the selected cell into a new view controller ..

My problem is that I can not view images in the new view controller, you can tell me how can I do? I'm trying to understand and investigate the argormento on various forums but can not find answers on the forum and Parse is a long time since I was left without answers.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Visual"]){

           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.Tork indexPathForSelectedRow];
           PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           ViewController  *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
           detailViewController.oggetto = object;  } }
```

TableView :

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"username"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"picture"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"email"];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork; }

    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];        
    return query;    }




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [object objectForKey:@"email"]];
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"none.png"];


    PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"picture"];
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply :) ... The problem seems to be solved .. I changed the following to prepare for this and it works now! What do you think? you seem suitable? until now has not caused the crash my app.

PfQueryTableViewController.m

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Visual"]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tavola indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFFile *file = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

        ViewController  *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.oggetto = object;
        detailViewController.file = file;
    }
}
```

DetailViewcontroller.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.nome.text = [oggetto objectForKey:@"username"];
    self.email.text = [oggetto objectForKey:@"email"];

    PFFile *imageFile = [oggetto objectForKey:@"foto"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.image.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];                       
    }];   
}
```

Now I am in trouble with this part of the code, I am adding a search bar with the display. The code returns no errors but not when beginning your search did not show any results. This is the code, you have ideas?

```
- (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully fetched %d entries", result.count);

         [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray: result];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}

- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"_User"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"username"];  //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKeyExists:@"foto"]; //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKeyExists:@"email"];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    query.limit = 50;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:error:)];


}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:  (NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}
```

The log tells me this but I do not displays the results on the device: (

**AssertMacros: queueEntry, file: / SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
09/13/2013 01:34:50.537 Unipot v.02 [412:60 b] Successfully fetched 9 entries**